# minor version dependency management (GIT, artifactory, dockers)

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, artifactory

assume I have projectA (1.0.0-SNAPSHOT) and projectB (1.0.0-SNAPSHOT) that needs projectA as dependency. now I've released everything on-prem, and converted all proj to 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT ([with this nice plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plugin+-+Release+Management)).

Now there was a bug in projectA (got the branch in GIT and fixed). what's the best practice - should I promote both projects to 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT? though projectB was not changed? or even more important - I now need to get to all clients of projectA, and change their pom to now point to PROJECTA-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT? seems quite manual and not clean? So - how to handle minor patches promotes in source control in a robust way? is it somthing I can do dynamically here? for example tell artifactory - "you take the latest 1.0.X of projectA ?"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this plugin, however, [SemVer](http://semver.org/) has some instructions for your problems. First, you should not promote the version of projectB because of PATCH number changes in its dependent projects. You must build the projectB when the change of projectA is in a Major or Minor level.

For the second problem, I think the mentioned plugin can change pom versions in source control (svn/git) server and your clients can update their own codes.